# Compiling newly changed files only in Maven Deploy

Tags: java, maven, deployment

We use Maven to for our web application and we used to use Ant.

When deploying in ANT, you can set it to not use war files and to only copy newly files into the deploy folder.  This is a tremendous time saver when working on your local machine.

In Maven, I'd like it to work the same way.  Whether there is a change in the main project or one of its dependencies, I'd like it to just recompile and copy the newly changed files.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I think if youjust do a mvn install it will do that. If you do a clean before it will clear the target directory and compile everything. Install will install it in your local repository ready to use in your war file

Comment: Install will package and update your local maven repository. When deploy will deploy created artifacts to the central repository. So in short `mvn install` should just be good.

Answer (score 1):

If you "deploy" by copying files from your project directory to, say, Tomcat `webapps` directory - do the same in Maven by means of [`maven-antrun-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/).

Otherwise, I would recommend to use either [cargo-maven2-plugin](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin) or [tomcat7-maven-plugin](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0-SNAPSHOT/tomcat7-maven-plugin/).